# Bootstrap - Right Align Icon Buttons in Header on Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a responsive site with Bootstrap. The site has a fixed nav bar. It works great on desktop. However, when the site is running on a mobile device, the icons in the upper right disappear. My code looks like this:

```
<div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="/home" class="navbar-brand"><img src="/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a id="viewButton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I right-align buttons in the navbar when in mobile view?

Thanks!

Comment: take them out of collapse.

Comment: Can you please provide a link?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/o9afso5q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have to remove the collapse classes from the div.
  http://www.bootply.com/F6jMrwYOQQ#

```
<div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="/home" class="navbar-brand"><img src="/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
          <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a id="viewButton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the collapse class here

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```